# I'm trying to add MouseListener to a Buttons array using a For loop, and is giving me a type mismatch error

Tags: java, oop

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class game extends Frame implements MouseListener{
//DECLARE
MenuBar mb;
Menu m1, m2, m3;
MenuItem mi1, mi2, mi3, mi4;
Panel gameBoard, header, footer; 
Button gb[]; 
Label announcer, score;

    game(){
        //FRAME ATRIBUTES
        super("TicTacToe");
        setSize(500,500);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        
        //INITIALIZE
        //MENUBAR
         mb = new MenuBar ();
         m1 = new Menu("Nuevo Juego");
         m2 = new Menu("Opciones");
         m3 = new Menu("Ayuda");
         mi1 = new MenuItem("");
         mi2 = new MenuItem("");
         mi3 = new MenuItem("");
         //PANEL
         header= new Panel();
         gameBoard = new Panel();
         footer = new Panel();
         announcer = new Label("Announcer:");
         score = new Label("Score:");
         //BUTTONS
         gb = new Button[9];

         //SETTING THE LAYOUTS TO ACCOMODATE THE GAME BOARD
         gameBoard.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));

        //CLOSING WINDOW EVENT
         this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){          
          public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
           System.exit(0);
          }      
         });
         
         //ADDING THE BUTTONS TO THE GAMEBOARD
         for(int i = 0; i < gb.length; i++){
            gb[i] = new Button();
            gameBoard.add(gb[i]);
            gb[i] = addMouseListener(this); //For some reason this is wrong... 
         }

     //ADD 
        setMenuBar(mb);
        mb.add(m1);
        mb.add(m2);
        mb.add(m3);
        header.add(score);
        footer.add(announcer);

    //ADD PANEL TO THE FRAME
        add(gameBoard, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(footer, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }
    
    //MOUSE EVENTS
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        //TESTING 
        if(e.getSource().equals(gb[0]))
            System.out.println("Presionaste la casilla 1.");
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
    
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
    
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}
    
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}

    public static void main(String[] args){

        game g = new game();

    }

}
```

I'm trying to add a mouselistener to each buttons so they can react, but its giving me this issue:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Button

I honestly don't understand what's wrong with it, tried asking ChatGPT but kept saying that i should change "gb[i] = addMouseListener(this);" to "gb[i] = addMouseListener(this);". Tried Google, no success. I feel like this error is going to be really easy to fix but I'm not seeing it, so please someone make me open my eyes. Thanks!

Tried CHATGPT and Google. I'm just trying to get this buttons to work to keep going with the game logic

Comment: Perhaps you meant `gb[i].addMouseListener(this);`.

Comment: Rather than asking _CharGPT_, maybe you should study a [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)?